# Query to get result from checking condition on two-more column from same table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table below:

```
RuleID |  Code    |    Value
654     Branch          54
654     MessageType     MT103
654     Currency        USD
654     SourceSys       xyz
<!--Comment-Another set of RuleID data-->
656     Branch          54
656     MessageType     MT102
656     Currency        INR
--------So ON -------------
<!--Comment-Another set of RuleID data-->
658     Branch          54
658     MessageType     MT103
658     Currency        INR
```

Every RuleID will max have 5 to 6 code and thier value.It may have 1 also 2 also. Here for example I have given 2 set values.one for Rule id 654 and other 656.

Now Need a query where I can get all RuleID where Branch = 54 and MessageType=MT102

I tried below:- (But this will obviuos not work)

```
select RuleID 
from MyTable 
where (CODE='Branch' and Value='54') 
 and  (CODE='MessageType' and Value='MT102')
```

Read the Union also but that also will not work here.

Think join should do here, but not getting result.

Expected Result: I want to Query all RuleID where Branch is 54 and MessageType is MT103. So Expected Result is Ruleid-654,658

Comment: With that sample data, what is the expected result?

Comment: Edited the Question with more data and expected Result

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR`.

```
SELECT RuleID 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE (CODE = 'Branch' AND Value = '54') 
OR (CODE = 'MessageType' AND Value = 'MT102')
```

Comment: Matt,Thats the problem, Logically I need the all rule ids where Branch is 54 and MessageType is MT102. the given query will result me also, if Branch is 54 and MessageType is not MT102.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
SQL> WITH test (ruleid, code, VALUE)
  2       AS (SELECT 654, 'Branch', '54' FROM DUAL
  3           UNION
  4           SELECT 654, 'MessageType', 'MT103' FROM DUAL
  5           UNION
  6           SELECT 654, 'Currency', 'USD' FROM DUAL
  7           UNION
  8           SELECT 654, 'SourceSys', 'xyz' FROM DUAL
  9           UNION
 10           --
 11           SELECT 656, 'Branch', '54' FROM DUAL
 12           UNION
 13           SELECT 656, 'MessageType', 'MT102' FROM DUAL
 14           UNION
 15           SELECT 656, 'Currency', 'INR' FROM DUAL)
 16    SELECT ruleid
 17      FROM test
 18     WHERE (   (    code = 'Branch'
 19                AND VALUE = '54')
 20            OR (    code = 'MessageType'
 21                AND VALUE = 'MT102'))
 22  GROUP BY ruleid
 23    HAVING COUNT (*) = 2;

    RULEID
----------
       656

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use intersection

```
WITH MyTable as 
(
  SELECT 654 RuleId, 'Branch' code, '54' value FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 654, 'MessageType', 'MT103' FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 654, 'Currency', 'USD' FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 654, 'SourceSys', 'xyz' FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 656, 'Branch', '54' FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 656, 'MessageType', 'MT102' FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 656, 'Currency', 'INR' FROM DUAL
)
select RuleID 
from   MyTable 
where  CODE='Branch' 
and    Value='54'
intersect
select RuleID 
from   MyTable 
where  CODE='MessageType' 
and    Value='MT102'
```

Comment: Yes Maxim, This seems is working,I am testing multiple Combination.

Comment: Can we include Null check into same Query? Means if given value is null then dont intesect the code

Comment: Well, If I understood you correctly, then there is no change for null, nulls are automatically excluded from the result set. Oracle treats null in a special way - the expression code = null or code = '' are never true, the result set for that is empty

Comment: No Not that Way, What I meant is here, Lets say MessageType which is userinput and is null then I should get all RuleID where Branch is 54. (MessageType,Branch is user input), they may provide the value or not. In short its filter query

Comment: I see your point. If you are able to construct the query dynamically in your application, then in case MessageType is null (which stands for "any values") - you can simply omit the intersection with MessageType query. But if you don't have a way to change the query and the only thing you change are the values - then you can replace the condition [value = 'MT102'] to this one [ (value = 'MT102' or 'MT102' is null) ]. So in case the user input is null then every rule is selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173321/discussion-between-samash-and-maxim-borunov).